# Posts come up in multiple review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I've found that some posts will show up in multiple review queues, for example a first post that is also a late answer, or a low-quality post that is also a late answer and/or a first post. This happens even after you've taken an action on the post in one of the queues.

A specific example I was reviewing the low-quality queue when I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/923506) that I thought should be deleted so I clicked the recommend deletion button, then I went to the late answer queue and saw that same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/923502), which I then flagged for deletion.

I think that if you have already taken an action on a post in one queue it shouldn't come for you in a different queue, especially when the action is something like recommend deletion in which case there isn't really anything else for you to "do" about the post.

**EDIT:**

There is a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112892/193563) that's similar to this question, but based on the date of that question it must be referring to the old review system.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, first off if you look at the date of the question it's obviously talking about the old-review system. Second my question is more about when you have taken an action already, especially if the action is recommending for deletion in which case there isn't anything further to *review*.

Comment: It's the same principle, isn't it? Questions are marked with multiple flags, and thus they show up in multiple queues in both the old and the new system.

Comment: I don't have access to the source code but I'm assuming they made changes to the way the system works when they rolled out the new review system.

Comment: Also [@waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) commented that he would look at *fixing* it (and perf was an issue), so it was fixed and this is a *new* issue, or it wasn't fixed and should be fixed now, or its been decided that it isn't worth fixing due to performance. Either way I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I can see an argument for preventing someone from coming across the same post in the Low Quality Posts, Late Answers, and First Posts queues. But it seems like the Suggested Edits, Close Votes, and Reopen Votes queues should be exempt from this. For example, if something has a reopen vote *and* a suggested edit, it seems reasonable to show both to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now. You should no longer see the same post in the First Posts, Late Answers, and Low Quality review queues.

It's still possible to come across the same post in the other queues though. For example, you might see something in Suggested Edits, and then later in the Reopen queue.

Comment: They still will be put in multiple queues though? It's just that an individual won't see them? It's a lot quicker to get rid of crap answers from the low quality queue you see, the others rely on people flagging ..

Comment: Yea, they'll still be put in multiple queues.