# Both buttons 'No Action Needed' and 'I'm Done' are sometimes enabled when reviewing an item you've already acted on

Tags: bug, review

If you review a post in the First Posts or Late Answers review queues, and you have already edited/voted on/commented on it, the item will already have the 'I'm Done' button enabled. Usually, the 'No Action Needed' button is disabled in those cases, but (in my experience) since 6-8 weeks, in 20%-40% of the times, it is not. See the screenshot below for an example:

[image]

I couldn't detect any pattern between the specific actions I've already taken on the post and whether the No Action Needed button is enabled or not.

[This post from 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158983/295232) is similar, but I'm pretty sure that request was already implemented and (as far as I know) it used to work correctly until a few months ago.

Comment: Might have the same root cause ... only I commented here and did not flag like you did. I've also seen it happening with votes. And I'm not sure about this instance, but in other cases reloading the review queue item did disable the No Action Needed button.