# All three buttons enabled while reviewing again

Tags: bug, review, flags

I have gotten reviews in First Posts for posts that I have already taken an action on "in the wild".

The first time, I had commented on a post. When I saw the post come up in review, "I'm Done" was already enabled, and "No Action Needed" was disabled. This is cool.

You might assume the same thing would happen when I flagged a question for closure, then saw it again in the queue. It didn't. For some reason, I had three options enabled, and a lot of confusion:

[image: All three enabled]

I was able to complete the review when I clicked "I'm Done", at least.

---

From what it says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147763/323179), I'm not even sure if I should be getting these reviews:

> As of now, if you have already taken some sort of action on a post, you shouldn't randomly come across it in the First Posts queue. However, if you directly navigate to it (via reloading the page, back/forward, or permalink), it should still be reviewable, with the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button enabled and clickable by default.

I reached the post through the review queue, not any of these methods:

- reloading the page, back/forward, or permalink

---

The same bug was already mentioned at [Both "No Action Needed" and "I'm Done" enabled when reviewing a post for the second time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158983), but that was 4 years ago and a slightly different situation. The situation would have changed due to [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170819/323179), obscuring the issue.